# Как в angularjs избавится от повторных запросов

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Делаю так, кидаю в Root  чтобы при переходе материалы были доступны, но я так понимаю это не совсем правильно и можно как то по другому достучаться до скоупа

```
portfolioControllers.controller('NewsCtrl', ['$scope','$rootScope', 'Permission', '$http', 'News', '$routeParams',
    function ($scope,$rootScope, Permission, $http, News, $routeParams) {
        homeAnimate = 0;
        if (!$rootScope.news) {
            $rootScope.news = new News();
            console.log('test');
            $rootScope.news.load();
        }
        if ($routeParams.item_id) {
            var find = false;
            angular.forEach($rootScope.news.items, function (value) {
                if (value.id == $routeParams.item_id) {
                    $rootScope.news.currentItem = value;
                    find = true;
                }
            });
            if (!find) {
                $rootScope.news.loadById({action: 'News', page: '1', id: $routeParams.item_id});
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Собственно сам News

```
portfolioServices.factory('News', function (Parent) {
    var service = function () {
        // инициализация родителя
        Parent.call(this);
        // свои свойства
        this.action = 'News';
        this.newItem = {
            action: this.action
        };
    };
    // наследование
    service.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
    service.prototype.constructor = service;


    return service;
});
```

Comment: что за повторные запросы и как к ним относится приведенный код?

Comment: да там где написано слово test  проверяется уходит ли запрос

Comment: и? можете описать проблему конкретнее? что делает приведенный кусок, что он делает не так?

Comment: и смысл в `new News();` ? а так же зачем использовать `$rootScope` если уже используется сервис `News`

Comment: @Grundy там не синглтон

Comment: Ну судя по предполагаемому использованию - лучше сделать его синглтоном

Comment: Добавил News может прояснит как то

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35714/discussion-between-grundy-and-serge-esmanovich).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Для сохранения данных, которые Вы хотите передать в другой `$scope` или сохранить во время роутинга можно использовать сервисы (`Service`). Поскольку сервис является `синглтоном`, то вы можете использовать его для хранения и расшаривания данных.

Посмотрите пример на [jsfidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/5m0hwbe1/).

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);


myApp.controller("ExampleOneController", function($scope, NewsService) {
  $scope.news = NewsService.news;
});
myApp.controller("ExampleTwoController", function($scope,NewsService) {
  $scope.news = NewsService.news;
});

myApp.service("NewsService", function() {
  return {
    news: [{theme:"This is one new"}, {theme:"This is two new"}, {theme:"This is three new"}]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleOneController">
    <h2>
  ExampleOneController
  </h2>
    <div ng-repeat="n in news">
      <textarea ng-model="n.theme"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ExampleTwoController">
    <h2>
  ExampleTwoController
  </h2>
  <div ng-repeat="n in news">
      <div>{{n.theme}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Да добавил в News return new service(); И все заработало так как хотел